# Using NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a number of NSString objects I want to save into an NSDictionary.

How is an NSDictionary initialized with the keys and do the values need to be set there and then or can the dictionary be setup using just the keys and the objects later set?

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation and/or look for tutorials for NSDictionary online. Here's one example: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary can be initialized both as empty or as a list of `(value,key)` pairs.

Initializing the dictionary just with keys and not values is useless/meaningless in Objective-C, since it will be equivalent to a void initialization.

If you want to create a dictionary and want to be able to set objects later, you have to use a `NSMutableDictionary`, that has not a static initialization of its data, through its `setObject:forKey:` method.

Comment: Can I write an NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries to a plist file in the documents folder?

Answer (score 3):

To start with here's a link to the NSDictionary [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can create a `NSMutableDictionary` with just keys by passing `[NSNull null]` as the object for that key. It's important to use a mutable dictionary here otherwise you won't be able to change the dictionary after you've created it, and a dictionary that just has keys instead of objects is of little use.

That is what [NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is for: to provide null values for collection types that don't allow nils.